# Php binary Tree In Mlm Software

Tags: mlm

Iam developing Mlm Software in Procedural Php-7,Now Strucked With Generation Of Bianary Tree (Parent,Left And Right Children Nodes).So Please Help Me,
I Have An Admin With Username 10000 So Admin May Add New Users And Every User Can Add Many Sub Users So That I Need To Construct genealogy Tree .
[I Have Database Table Structre Like This](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ImBrJ.png)
[Table Structure]

[And I need To Generate Tree Like This](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bW9GM.png)

Comment: Welcome to stack overflow please take a [tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour)
then read [how to ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)
to get the best answer possible.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you were using LARAVEL there's a package you can use.

https://github.com/lazychaser/laravel-nestedset

And a video to describe the use

https://youtu.be/9PEjGW2EvRI

I'm also building an mlm site the problem I have is how to visualize the binary tree